# Adding a Shared project to multiple projects

Tags: java, eclipse, dependencies, shared

I have 3 different projects that use some global stuff
So i created a 4th project that is called "Shared Project"

Now, If i add this project to each of the other project's class path (via eclipse - > java build path - projects - > add "Shared Project"

I can debug with the shared stuff and its working well. But when i export the project into a WAR the files from the dependent project are missing

What I would like to do is - when i export a project to war it will add the shared project as a jar as well.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on the spring web project, and select Properties, and select Deployment assembly. Here you can add projects .  Later when you export as war, dependancy classes will be jared in to lib folder

[image]

Comment: Its a spring web project, and when i choose export WAR, i can choose only one project